# Connection between the Fourier transform of a measure and the support of the measure

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a separable real Hilbert space, $\mu$ a complex finite Borel measure on it with Fourier transform $\hat \mu$, and $V$ a finite dimensional subspace. Let $P : H \to V$ be the orthogonal projector onto $V$. Show that if $\hat \mu = \hat \mu \circ P$ (composition of functions), then $\text{supp} \ \mu \subseteq V$.

The trouble with this one is that I really do not know where to start from, even though intuitively I can understand what happens here. I tried to show that if $U \subseteq H \setminus V$ is an open subset, then $\int \limits _H 1_U \ \Bbb d \mu = 0$, but I failed to connect this with the $\Bbb e ^{\Bbb i \langle x, y \rangle }$ in $\hat \mu$. How to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose for now $\mu$ real.
Let $|\mu|^{\perp}$ the pushforward of $|\mu|$ with respect to the projection $P^{\perp}:H\rightarrow V^{\perp}$. Using the hypothesis and a change of variables, we get that for every $y\in V^{\perp}$,
$$\widehat{|\mu|^{\perp}}(y) =
\int \limits_{V^{\perp}}e^{i(x,y)}d|\mu|^{\perp}(x) =
\int \limits_He^{i(P^\perp x,y)}d|\mu|(x) =
\int \limits_He^{i(x,P^\perp y)}d|\mu|(x) =
\widehat {|\mu|} (P^\perp y) = \\
\widehat {|\mu|} \circ P (P^\perp y) =
\widehat {|\mu|} (0) =
\int \limits_He^{i(x,0)}d|\mu|(x) =
\int \limits_He^{i(P^\perp x,0)}d|\mu|(x) =
\int \limits_{V^{\perp}}e^{i(x,0)}d|\mu|^{\perp}(x) =
\widehat {|\mu|^\perp} (0) ,$$

so $\widehat {|\mu|^\perp}$ is a constant function (equal to $\widehat {|\mu|} (0) = |\mu| (H)$). But the measure $|\mu|(H)\delta_0$ has exactly the same Fourier transform on $V^\perp$, so necessarily $|\mu|^{\perp}=|\mu|(H)\delta_0$ on $V^{\perp}$.

Now, given $U\subset H\backslash V$, we  have $U\subset  (P^{\perp})^{-1}P^{\perp}U$. Since $0\not\in P^{\perp}U$, $|\mu|$ is monotonic and $\mu\leq |\mu|$, we have
$$\mu (U) \le |\mu|(U) \le |\mu|((P^{\perp})^{-1}P^{\perp}U)=|\mu|^{\perp}(P^{\perp}U)=0 ,$$

so $\mu(U)=0$.

Now, if $\mu$ is complex, one can separate its real and imaginary part and apply
the previous case to both.

Comment: $\mu$ is a complex measure. What do you mean by "monotonicity" in this case?

Comment: Also, on the first line of formulae (the one with integrals), why is the third equality true (the one where you replace $y$ by $0$)?

Comment: The third inequality follows from that fact that $P(y)=0$ if $y\in V^{\perp}$. I have edited my answer to include the complex case.

Comment: While studying your answer, I have edited it to make it clearer to me and to future readers. Tell me if you agree with the changes, in order for me to close the question (otherwise, feel free to roll back to the previous version).

Comment: It's ok for me.